# Branch Coverage is not showing in lcov Report for mock Functions

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I'm trying to use lcov for code coverage metrics, but Branch coverage report showing not covered for mock functions.

[Attached image of report for reference purpose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK3c9.png)

Answer (score 0):

by adding  -fno-exceptions flags in CMake we resolved above issue

example:
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -fno-exceptions -fno-inline")